# Why do gyms in the US want their customers to fill out a waiver, rather than just having a sign on the wall about the T&Cs?

Tags: united-states, waivers

Whenever you participate in a gym or some other related facility such as a rock climbing gym, the business forces you to fill out an annoying long waiver where you promise not to sue them if you accidentally kill yourself with a barbell. But why is this the case? Couldn't the gym just hang a giant "you may die if you enter this door" sign in the front and absolve themselves of all responsibility?

I've been a member of several gyms when I lived in Europe and never had to sign a waiver, so I do know its legally possible in some jurisdictions.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite doesn't seem to be a problem in many other areas of law - i.e. there's no contract to sign when you board a bus, but you can still be charged for fare evasion.

Comment: You might see that a signature is better proof that the notice was actually seen, and something  tangible to take into court. Regarding a sign - how to prove a sign was up on a specific day?

Comment: @GeorgeWhite how does a public transit company prove that it had a sign about needing to pay before entering the bus? And how does it work in Europe where no waivers are required, in at least some countries?

Comment: I commented rather than answered becasue I do not have a full understanding. I see someone knowledgeable has given an actual answer.

Comment: @JonathanReez fare evasion is usually forbidden by law, at least in the US. Therefore, no explicit contract is necessary. For example, [M.G.L. ch.159A §16](https://malegislature.gov/Laws/GeneralLaws/PartI/TitleXXII/Chapter159a/Section16) covers evasion of bus fare in MA (among other statutes).

Answer (score 3):

A signed waiver provides more definitive proof of knowledge and consent than a sign posted on a wall.